# Why No More Memory Allocation in This App of Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, memory-limit

We have a server running 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04, which is serving a django application running under virtual environment, along with a celery worker. 
The problem is no process in the server uses more than 2GB of memory. There are 8GB of memory available in the system with 4GB of swap. This graph shows that the process is rather limited by some factor

[image]

We did not do anything to enforce running processes in 32 bits or anything. 
I should also note that both the django and celery are monitored by supervisor process manager and `newrelic-client`, I do not know if those have anything to do with the memory limit.

Why does the celery process not allocate more memory if it needs to?

System: Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit
Client: Django application (2 GB)
RAM: 8 GB
Swap: 4 GB